# How can I specify which IP address is used for outbound traffic in OS X Lion Server with multiple WAN IPs?

Tags: nat, mac-osx-server, osx-lion

I have a Mac Mini Server running OS X 10.7.4 (Lion). I am using the ethernet port for the LAN and I have a USB->Ethernet adapter for the WAN. I have assigned two external IPs to the USB->Ethernet (lets call them x.x.x.120 & x.x.x.121). The server’s “main” IP address is x.x.x.120 and that is the IP address that the FQDN hostname is DNSed to.

It appears that in OS X the outbound traffic goes over the first interface in the Service Order list, but putting x.x.x.121 first seems to make the machine think that the hostname/IP doesn’t properly match when using `changeip -checkhostname`.

How do I specify that **all** outbound traffic should go over x.x.x.121 both from that machine and from the machines on the LAN behind NAT.